# Trying to change word with React-Countdown-Circle-Timer?

Tags: reactjs

I have the timer within a sentence: 'You have (timer) seconds left. I would like for seconds to say second when the timer hits one. For more info I am also using the oncomplete prop of the timer and the key prop to reset the timer when the user wants.
I'm doing this all in React.

Here is the code I have

```
const renderTime = (time) => {
  return (
    <div className="time-wrapper">
      <div className="title time">{time}</div>
    </div>
  );
};

const renderTimer = () => {
 return (
   <div>
     You have {' '}
     <p>
       <CountdownCircleTimer>
       {timerProps}
       </CountdownCircleTimer>
     </p>{' '} seconds left.
  </div>
 )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

here is your answer, a control logic for displaying second instead of second, if theres 0-1 seconds remaining in the timer.

const renderTime = (time) => {
return (

{time}

);
};

```
const renderTimer = () => {
 return (
   <div>
     You have {' '}
     <p>
       <CountdownCircleTimer>
       {timerProps}
       </CountdownCircleTimer>
     </p>`${parseInt(timerProps) > 1 ? 'seconds' : 'second'}` left.
  </div>
 )
}
```